# Why is my command history empty?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I am using Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and I normally use the command history a lot. However, every time I reboot my computer, the command history is gone and it is annoying! Can anybody explain me how could I keep the command history?

Comment: I think this question should be asked on askubuntu.com and after searching a little, it already has an answer [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/31137/655910)

Comment: @Siraj while it is on topic there it is also completely on topic here as well. It *can* be asked there just as it can be asked here, it does not *have* to be asked there if op chooses here instead.

Comment: What if you delete ~/.bash_history and recreate it using touch ~/.bash_history ?

Comment: That fixed it! I had no permission to access .bash_history and after removing it with sudo rm .bash_history and creating it again, I can type history successfully

Answer (score 3):

The same just happened to me. The reason was that the first command I issued after setting up my account was with `sudo`. Therefore, my `~/.bash_history` was owned by `root` and could not be updated by my user. The following command fixed it for me:

```
sudo chown $USER ~/.bash_history
```